# How to design a social media follower/followed relation with UML?

Tags: design, uml, composition

I am working on a UML diagram for social media website like Facebook:

- The main class of this system is `User`, which has members as userid, email, phone, address, Friends, etc.
- A user may follow a set of users. So several users may follow a given user, and a given user may follow several other users.

Does it make sense to store this information about followed and following users in the `User` object? If yes, then do I need to maintain two set of information in a `User` (who follows the user and whom the user follows)?

I think that only one piece of information out of these two should be maintained: the list of users who follows a user because user-followers is an has-a relationship. But if a user follows someone, then it is not a has-a relationship, but there can be a method  in `User` class that return set of users, a user follow. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to start?

A UML class diagram aims to help you design classes before getting lost in the implementation of the details.  In this regard,  what matters here seems to be:

- The `User` [class](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html) and the [properties](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html?context=class-diagrams) directly linked to a user (e.g.`userid`,`email`,`phone`,`address`) as well as a first set of [operations](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html) that can be done on a user;
- The `follows` [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams) between two `User`;
- The <strike>`friendzoned`</strike> `befriended`association between two `User`;
- The [multiplicity](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html?context=class-diagrams) of the associations (in both case, many-to-many, for example a user can follow many other users, and a user can be followed by many other users)

[image]

I assumed here that being friends (which is symmetric) is unrelated to following someone (which is unilateral). But different assumptions may lead to different designs.

The next question, is whether the identified associations have some properties or behaviors by themselves.  For example:

- `follows`  could be enriched with the start date of the following, and maybe a priority in the news-thread.
- `befriended`  could be related to a kind of friendship (e.g. family, colleagues, or friends)

If yes, you may want to make the association and association class.
[image]

### How to implement the design?

That's the UML design. It's easy to draw lines between related elements.  When the ideas are clear, you can think of implementing.  For many-to-many associations,  you could typically use one of the following approaches:

- duplicate the information (i.e. `user1` would have in the collection of friends `user2`, and `user2` would have `user1` as friend, and `user1.addFriend(user3)` would automatically  update the collection of friends in both objects).
- manage the association as a separate class that would deal with pairs of related friends (i.e. `user1` and `user2` would not be directly connect,  but would rely on a `befriended` to find their respective friends. This is typically what you'd do if you have a [RDBMS implementation](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html) in mind).

Finally, it's worth to mention that such a social network is in fact a graph.  `User` are nodes  and `befriended` and `following` are edges between nodes.  If you go for a graph implementation,  you'd immediately have the benefit of all the graph algorithms,  such as transitive closure, shortest path, spanning tree, etc...

Comment: Can i manager these associations(1-1,1-M,M:M), the way we manage in ER-Diagram?In that we can map 1-1 by storing association in any table and 1-M by storing associations on M side and M:M are handled in the way by persisting associations on separate table means separate class?

Comment: @rahulsharma yes, that’s perfectly possible. That’s the way you’d do it if implementing with an RDBMS. In an OO language however, storing the link back to 1 on the M side allows you to navigate back, but only with difficulty naviate from the 1 to the M. Therefore usually the M side is stored in a collection on the 1 side.

Comment: One small doubt regarding your last comment.If we have a 1:M mapping and we store M side as a collection on one side,now if we also store 1 on M side, is it against OO principles?Are there any use cases for these?Like a E-commerce user and  orders has 1:M mapping.One user can have many orders but an order can be placed by one user.We will store List of Orders with user.If we also store user information with order,does this violate any principles/practices?Is it a valid use case?

Comment: @rahulsharma no, that's not against OO.  The question is what navigation you need.  Depending on your design and your algorithm,  you may not necessarily need the link back to 1.  If you need bidirectional navigation, you'll need two links for getting the two directions. It's not  bad,  it's just that you need to ensure to keep both links consistent.  Many OO languages offer classes with reference semantic.  You can then have one same object in multiple collections:  the collection just storse the link and not a  duplicate.

Comment: ok.Do you know any good resources where I can find good clarification and understanding on Association with 1:1,1:M,M:N and same for Aggregation and Composition.I am getting a lot of confusion sometimes.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I've learnt this a long time ago, and have no resources to recommend on this specific subject. But I'm sure you'll learn quickly by trying solutions in your projects. ANd asking for resources is out of scope here.

Comment: its been a long discussion, but one more point i would like to clear if possible,In case of one to many aggregation/composition,it is always better to store M side collection on 1 side.But in case of association of 1:M, we will place 1 on M side?Like a association namely "sends", between user and message,user "sends" message, class is 1:M,but it does not make sense to have Collection of messages with user.It will be better to have user information with message to indicate which user has send it.Am i correct?